# Solving $T(n) = 2T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + n^3$

Tags: asymptotics

How can I solve this recursive function using substitution method?

$$T(n) = 2T(n/3) + T (2n/3) + n^3$$

I substitute $T(n/3)$ and after that $T(n/9)$. when it goes to k-step, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Akra-Bazzi theorem as

$$g(x) = n^3 \in O(n^c), a_1=2, a_2 = 1, b_1 = \frac{1}{3}, b_2 = \frac{2}{3}$$

So, just we need to find $p$ such that:

$$2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^p + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^p = 1$$

You can find the computation for finding $p$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%20%281%2F3%29%5Ep%20%20%2B%20%20%282%2F3%29%5Ep%20%3D%201). It is around $1.4$. Now, we can write:

$$T(n) \in \Theta\left(n^{p}\left(1 +‌ \int_{1}^{n}\frac{u^3}{u^{1+p}}du\right)\right)$$

To simplify the term, we can write:

$$
\int_{1}^{n}\frac{u^3}{u^{1+p}}du = \int_{1}^{n}u^{2-p}du = \frac{1}{3-p}u^{3-p} |_1^n = \frac{1}{3-p}(n^{3-p}-1)
$$

Now, by substituting this term in the main complexity term, we can conclude that $T(n) \in \Theta(n^3)$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question but won't p has to be equal to 1 to apply this theorem?

Comment: @DineshThapa my pleasure. Of course not! The only constraint over $p$ is it should satisfy the equation that I've mentioned, i.e., $2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^p + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^p = 1$

Comment: that clears my confusion and one last thing when you substitute that value of integration in T(n) did you ceil the value of p?

Comment: @DineshThapa 1.4 is the ceil, but I didn't substitute that! You can see it will be canceled when multiplying $n^p$ to $n^{3-p}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use proof by induction, ignoring for a moment the fact that $n/3$ and $2n/3$ are not always integers. We aim at a bound of the form $Cn^3$, which for large enough $C$ will satisfy the base case. As for the inductive step:
$$
T(n) = 2T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + n^3 \leq 2C(n/3)^3 + C(2n/3)^3 + n^3 = \left(\frac{10}{27}C + 1\right)n^3.
$$
This is bounded by $Cn^3$ for all $C \geq 27/17$.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the other two answers: The term $...+ n^3$ means the solution cannot be less than $O(n^3)$. At this point you can guess that the p from the Akra-Bazzi Theorem is less than 3, in that case the proof by complete induction works (lucky you!)

Same problem with a term $... + n^{1.2}$, proof by induction that $T(n) = O(n^{1.2}) would fail, so you would have to go the complicated route following OmG’s answer.